# Where to put .ttf files Folder which comes with font awesome 4.03 in cake php 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am New to CakePhp and want to learn more about it because of it's flexibility.But am having a bit of a prob already.

I have this project of mine where iam using font awesome in CakePhp.
When i extracted the zip file of Font-Awesome i found "font-awesome.css " and a Folder name "fonts".

Well i have included the "font-awesome.css " in my default.ctp and copy the css file in "app/webroot/css folder".

Like this

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome');?>
 <body>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-3x"> MyAttendence</i>
 </body>
```

but i don't know where to put the "fonts" folder, i have tried placing this folder inside webroot/files/ but still no luck .

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FontAwesome` is including font files like `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3`, so you should try to put them in `webroot/fonts` (like `webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`)

Comment: Just Tried changing the path in font-awesome.css from ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3' to webroot/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3 But still no luck ...

Comment: If the files are in `webroot/fonts`, then in the CSS file you should either keep `../fonts/` or `/fonts/`

Comment: I was having the same issue and double checked the variable in _variables.scss and recompiled for Cake 2.6 and it's having an issue getting the font resources. Any help?